# Concatenation of Keras parallel layers changes wanted target shape

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, keras, keras-layer

I'm a bit new to Keras and deep learning. I'm currently trying to replicate this [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4afe/f0c6039a5d8b647518b6fe05f47a8bd3aeee.pdf) but when I'm compiling the first model (without the LSTMs) I get the following error:

> "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (None, 120, 40) but got array with shape (8, 40, 1)"

The description of the model is this:

1. Input (length `T` is appliance specific window size)
2. Parallel 1D convolution with filter `size` 3, 5, and 7
   respectively, `stride=1`, `number of filters=32`,
   `activation type=linear`, `border mode=same`
3. Merge layer which concatenates the output of
   parallel 1D convolutions
4. Dense layer, `output_dim=128`, `activation type=ReLU`
5. Dense layer, `output_dim=128`, `activation type=ReLU`
6. Dense layer, `output_dim=T` , `activation type=linear`

My code is this:

```
from keras import layers, Input
from keras.models import Model

# the window sizes (seq_length?) are 40, 1075, 465, 72 and 1246 for the kettle, dish washer,
# fridge, microwave, oven and washing machine, respectively.

def ae_net(T):
    input_layer = Input(shape= (T,))
    branch_a = layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation= 'linear', padding='same', strides=1)(input_layer)
    branch_b = layers.Conv1D(32, 5, activation= 'linear', padding='same', strides=1)(input_layer)
    branch_c = layers.Conv1D(32, 7, activation= 'linear', padding='same', strides=1)(input_layer)

    merge_layer = layers.concatenate([branch_a, branch_b, branch_c], axis=1)

    dense_1 = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(merge_layer)
    dense_2 =layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(dense_1)
    output_dense = layers.Dense(T, activation='linear')(dense_2)
    model = Model(input_layer, output_dense)
    return model

model = ae_net(40)
model.compile(loss= 'mean_absolute_error', optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit(X, y, batch_size= 8)
```

where `X` and `y` are `numpy arrays` of 8 sequences of a length of 40 values. So `X.shape` and `y.shape` are `(8, 40, 1)`. It's actually one batch of data. The thing is I cannot understand how the output would be of shape `(None, 120, 40)` and what these sizes would mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, your shapes contain `batch_size`, `length` and `channels`: **(8,40,1)**

Your three convolutions are, each one, creating a tensor like `(8,40,32)`.
Your concatenation in the `axis=1` creates a tensor like `(8,120,32)`, where `120 = 3*40`.

Now, the dense layers only work on the last dimension (the channels in this case), leaving the length (now 120) untouched.

### **Solution**

Now, it seems you do want to keep the length at the end. So you won't need any flatten or reshape layers. But you will need to keep the length 40, though.

You're probably doing the concatenation in the wrong axis. Instead of the length axis (1), you should concatenate in the channels axis (2 or -1).

So, this should be your concatenate layer:

```
merge_layer = layers.Concatenate()([branch_a, branch_b, branch_c])
#or layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([branch_a, branch_b, branch_c])
```

This will output `(8, 40, 96)`, and the dense layers will transform the 96 in something else.

Comment: Just tried to edit my code with your solution but now I'm getting a different error, irrelevant with the correction. The error is:
    "ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_3: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2"
in the line with the first convolution layer (branch_a).
I cannot figure out why this pops up even when I run what seems to be identical previously working to this point code.

Comment: `input_layer = Input(shape= (T,1))`

Comment: Figured this out but now I get the following error:
`"ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (None, 40, 40) but got array with shape (8, 40, 1)"`
with concatenation on axis=-1

Comment: This problem is here: `output_dense = layers.Dense(T, activation='linear')(dense_2)`. Your last dense layer should have only 1 neuron (instead of T) if your data has only one value (8,40,1).

Comment: It's a seq2se problem and I want the output to be a sequence of the same length as the input. I copied the parameters from the description of the model I found in the paper (as I posted it in my original post). I'll try to run it the way you suggested and come back with feedback. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It worked! Thank you! :) I have another problem with the second model right now but probably I should post another question about that.

Comment: Ok :) -- If you consider this answers your question, please mark it as answered :)

Comment: I have just posted the problem I have with the second network [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407346/typeerror-when-trying-to-create-a-blstm-network-in-keras). Take a look when you have the time! Thanks a lot! :)