# TypeError when trying to create a BLSTM network in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

I'm a bit new to Keras and deep learning. I'm currently trying to replicate this [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4afe/f0c6039a5d8b647518b6fe05f47a8bd3aeee.pdf) but when I'm compiling the second model (with the LSTMs) I get the following error:

```
"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'"
```

The description of the model is this:

1. Input (length `T` is appliance specific window size)
2. Parallel 1D convolution with filter `size` 3, 5, and 7
   respectively, `stride=1`, `number of filters=32`,
   `activation type=linear`, `border mode=same`
3. Merge layer which concatenates the output of
   parallel 1D convolutions
4. Bidirectional LSTM consists of a forward LSTM
   and a backward LSTM, `output_dim=128`
5. Bidirectional LSTM consists of a forward LSTM
   and a backward LSTM, `output_dim=128`
6. Dense layer, `output_dim=128`, `activation type=ReLU`
7. Dense layer, `output_dim= T` , `activation type=linear`

My code is this:

```
from keras import layers, Input
from keras.models import Model

def lstm_net(T):
    input_layer = Input(shape=(T,1))
    branch_a = layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation='linear', padding='same', strides=1)(input_layer)
    branch_b = layers.Conv1D(32, 5, activation='linear', padding='same', strides=1)(input_layer)
    branch_c = layers.Conv1D(32, 7, activation='linear', padding='same', strides=1)(input_layer)

    merge_layer = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([branch_a, branch_b, branch_c])
    print(merge_layer.shape)
    BLSTM1 = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, input_shape=(8,40,96)))(merge_layer)
    print(BLSTM1.shape)
    BLSTM2 = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128))(BLSTM1)
    dense_layer = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(BLSTM2)
    output_dense = layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(dense_layer)
    model = Model(input_layer, output_dense)
    model.name = "lstm_net"
    return model

model = lstm_net(40)
```

After that I get the above error. My goal is to give as input a batch of 8 sequences of length 40 and get as output a batch of 8 sequences of length 40 too. I found this issue on Keras Github [LSTM layer cannot connect to Dense layer after Flatten #818](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/818) and there @fchollet suggests that I should specify the 'input_shape' in the first layer which I did but probably not correctly. I put the two print statements to see how the shape is changing and the output is:

```
(?, 40, 96)
(?, 256)
```

The error occurs on the line BLSTM2 is defined and can be seen in full [here](https://prnt.sc/i4iqjo)

Comment: Please post at which line of the code this error appears.

Comment: It's on the last line of my post :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in these three lines:

```
BLSTM1 = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, input_shape=(8,40,96)))(merge_layer)
print(BLSTM1.shape)
BLSTM2 = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128))(BLSTM1)
```

As a default, `LSTM` is returning only the last element of computations - so your data is losing its sequential nature. That's why the proceeding layer raises an error. Change this line to:

```
BLSTM1 = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(merge_layer)
print(BLSTM1.shape)
BLSTM2 = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(128))(BLSTM1)
```

In order to make the input to the second `LSTM` to have sequential nature also.

Aside of this - I'd rather not use `input_shape` in middle model layer as it's automatically inferred.

Comment: You are right! I tried what you suggested and got an error during fitting about a difference between the dimensions provided to the Dense layer after the BLSTM2 and the ones expected. So, I put the argument `return_sequnces= True` to BLSTM2 layer too and it worked! Now, I'm not entirely sure if my network is like the one described in the paper. Does the `Bidirectional` layer contain 2 LSTMs? If so, then I think I'm OK.

Comment: Yes - it contains two `LSTM`s.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I thought I had already done that! Thanks a lot! :)